# How to get a text from disable text box

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
<i> 
  <input id="date-day" class="myclass" type="text"
    value="" readonly="readonly" placeholder="DD"
    name="EarliestLiveDateDD" maxlength="2"
    data-val-required="The Earliest Delivery date: field is required."
    data-val-number="The field Earliest Delivery date: must be a number."
    data-val="true"/>
  ,
</i>
```

Textbox value showing is 22

tried with get text and get Attribute but not able to get text.

Comment: <input id="date-day" class="myclass" type="text" value="" readonly="readonly" placeholder="DD" name="EarliestLiveDateDD" maxlength="2" data-val-required="The Earliest Delivery date: field is required." data-val-number="The field Earliest Delivery date: must be a number." data-val="true"/>

Comment: Please refer  above html code to get text

Comment: Please add the html code to your question! Also, exactly which element are you going for? Post the code you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("date-day")).GetAttribute("value");
```